# How to replace the next three characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

If the pattern has characters 'ai' or 'hi', replace the next three characters with * \ *

```
string = """
Or help one fainting robin
Unto his nest again,
I shall not live in vain
"""
```

The output should be:

> Or help one fai*\*ng robin
>   Unto hi*\*est again,
>   I shall not live in vain.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you running into?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and (2) Why is voting important? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.  -- Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for such an immediate response. I figured out the replacement part but was not able to go forward with the next characters. @TkTech

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(r"([ah]i).{3}", r"\1*/*", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import re

strings_to_find = ['ai', 'hi']

data = 'Or help one fainting robin Unto his nest again'
for string_to_find in strings_to_find:
    offsets = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(string_to_find, data)]
    for offset in offsets:
        data = data[:offset + len(string_to_find)] + '*\*' + data[offset + len(string_to_find) + 3:]
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the current char is "a" and the next is "i" or the other option ("h" and "i").

Let's do some code:

```py
string = "Or help one fainting robin Unto his nest again, I shall not live in vain"
string_new = string.split()

>>> string_new
['Or', 'help', 'one', 'fainting', 'robin', 'Unto', 'his', 'nest', 'again,', 'I', 'shall', 'not', 'live', 'in', 'vain']

for phrase in string_new:
    for i in range(len(phrase)):
        if (phrase[i] == "a" and phrase[i+1] == "i") or (phrase[i] == "h" and phrase[i+1] == "i"):
            print(phrase)
```

I splitted the String into a new String (removed the spaces into a String and the other, having as result a vector of Strings).

Next I'm running the vector string by string with the first `for`. With the second for I'm running the entire string char by char. Then I do some checks to identify if my string has a "ai" or "hi". If the String has some of these characters I print them.

**Now, you have only to change the respective char for a char you want**